# Wbadmin & powershell - latest backup version identifier

Tags: powershell

I need to get the latest backups version identifier in a powershell script.  If I run wbadmin get versions, I get a list of backups and the last one is the one I need.

Is there a way to do a kind of `select top 1 version identifier from backups order by date` or parsing the wbadmin output and getting this.

**edit**

It may be the windows.serverbackup module and versionId of Get-WBBackupSet I'm looking for but still need help parsing this.

```
VersionId        : 04/17/2013-21:00
BackupTime       : 17/04/2013 22:00:55
BackupTarget     : U:
RecoverableItems : Volumes, SystemState, Applications, Files, BareMetalRecovery
Volume           : {System Reserved, Local disk (C:), Local disk (I:), Local disk (O:)...}
Application      : {"Cluster", "Registry", "Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer"}
VssBackupOption  : VssFullBackup
SnapshotId       : 58999c7d-dfbf-4272-a5b9-21361d171486
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see how one object looks like. Can you post an example of it? @(Get-WBBackupSet)[0] | fl *

Comment: I've added one of the objects from the list.

Comment: I think I've got it with $backup = Get-WBBackupSet $version=$backup[-1].VersionId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try, Use -Last instead of -First to get the last item:

```
Get-WBBackupSet | 
Sort-Object BackupTime | 
Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty VersionId
```

You can also play with the order of sorting with the -Ascending switch

Comment: Thanks, makes my solution look like a hack. I must learn Powershell!

Answer (score 3):

Edit: revised version

For use with mixed environments (Windows Server 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2012R2 as of this writing):

```
function Get-MyWBSummary
{
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Retrieves the history of backup operations on the local or any number of remote computers.

    .DESCRIPTION
        The Get-MyWBSummary cmdlet retrieves the history of backup operations on the local or any number of remote computers with remoting enabled. This information includes backuptime, backuplocation, bersion identifier and recovery information.  
        To use this cmdlet, you must be a member of the Administrators group or Backup Operators group on the local or remote computer, or supply credentials that are.

    .PARAMETER ComputerName
        Retrives backup results on the specified computers. The default is the local computer.
        Type the NetBIOS name, an IP address, or a fully qualified domain name of one or more computers. To specify the local computer ignore the ComputerName parameter.
        This parameter rely on Windows PowerShell remoting, so your computer has to be configured to run remote commands.

    .PARAMETER Credential
        Specifies a user account that has permission to perform this action. The default is the current user. Type a user name, such as "User01", "Domain01\User01", or User@Contoso.com. Or, enter a PSCredential object, such as an object that is returned by the Get-Credential cmdlet. When you type a user name, you are prompted for a password.

    .PARAMETER Last
        Specifies the last (newest/latest) backup versions.

    .EXAMPLE 
        Get-MyWBSummary
        Retrieves all Windows Server backupversions from the local computer

    .EXAMPLE 
        Get-MyWBSummary | Where BackupTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
        Retrieves all Windows Server backupversions from the local computer within the last week    

    .EXAMPLE 
        Get-MyWBSummary -ComputerName $server1, $server2 -Last 1 -Credential $credential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable sessionErrors         
        Retrieves the last (newest) Windows Server Backup backupversion from remote servers $server1 and $server2

    .NOTES
        Written by Anders Præstegaard (@aPowershell).
        Version 1.0 (20-01-2016)
#>  
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([PSCustomObject])]
    param
    (
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential,
        [int]$Last
    )

    begin
    {
        if ($Credential)
        {
            $PSDefaultParameterValues['New-PSSession:Credential'] = $Credential
        }

        $psSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
    }
    Process
    {

        $scriptBlock = {

            if (-not (Test-Path -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\wbadmin.exe'))
            {
                ## Windows Server Backup not installed
                continue
            }

            $content = WBAdmin.exe GET VERSIONS
            if (-not $content)
            {
                ## no versions found
                continue
            }

            ## Get linenumbers for each entity
            $newJobLines = @($content | Select-String -Pattern 'Backup time: ')

            if ($Using:Last -and $using:Last -lt $newJobLines.Count)
            {
                $newJobLines = $newJobLines[- $using:Last.. -1]
            }

            $newJobLines |
            ForEach-Object{
                ## Location
                $lineNumberLocation = $_.LineNumber
                $backupLocation = $content[$lineNumberLocation] -replace 'Backup location: '

                ## Version Identifier
                $lineNumberVersionIdentifier = $_.LineNumber + 1
                $backupVersionIdentifier = $content[$lineNumberVersionIdentifier] -replace 'Version identifier: '

                ## Backuptime UTC
                # Version identifier string in WBAdmin output represents the UTC datetime formated in 'MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm'
                $wbAdminDateStringFormat = 'MM\/dd\/yyyy-HH:mm'
                $backupDateTimeFromVersionIdentifier = [DateTime]::ParseExact($backupVersionIdentifier, $wbAdminDateStringFormat, $null)
                $backupDateTimeUtcSpecified = [DateTime]::SpecifyKind($backupDateTimeFromVersionIdentifier, [System.DateTimeKind]::Utc)
                # NB WBAdmin calculates the time statically compared to your timezone (ie +1 hour)
                # If your timezone support "Daylight Saving Time" then WBAdmin calculation is wrong 
                # ~ half of the year (as far as I can perceive)
                $backupDateTimeLocalTime = $backupDateTimeUtcSpecified.ToLocalTime()

                ## Can recover
                $lineNumberCanRecover = $_.LineNumber + 2
                $backupVersionCanRecover = $content[$lineNumberCanRecover] -replace 'Can recover: '

                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    BackupTime = $backupDateTimeLocalTime
                    BackupTimeUtc = $backupDateTimeUtcSpecified
                    BackupLocation = $backupLocation
                    VersionIdentifier = $backupVersionIdentifier
                    CanRecover = $backupVersionCanRecover
                }
            }

        } # Scriptblock

        Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock |
        Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId
    }
    end
    {
        if ($psSession)
        {
            Remove-PSSession -Session $psSession
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Few years later and this still works on windows 10 and 11 computers. I made improvements like loop for all network computers and also to start/stop WinRM service before/after this great script.